# Erro laravel 5.6 "Undefined property"

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Estou tentando listar uma tabela de associação, no meu caso é a tabela turma, que associa funcionarios(professores) e alunos.

Dei uma boa pesquisada antes de postar está pergunta mas não consegui resolver o problema.

model Funcionario

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;


class Funcionario extends Authenticatable
#class Funcionario extends Model

{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
    'login','password','nome', 'sobrenome', 'nome_completo','rg','cpf','email',
    'cargo', 'data_registro','data_nascimento', 'nivel_acesso', 'sexo',
    'telefone','telefone2',
    'cidade','endereco','bairro','numero','cep','estado_id','escola_id',    
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password','remember_token'
    ];

    public function estado()
    {        
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Estado');
    }

    public function escola()
    {    
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Escola'); 
    }

    public function alunos()
    {    
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Aluno','turmas','funcionario_id','aluno_id')
        ->withPivot('serie','nome','nivel','professor','periodo','id'); 
    }

    
}
```

model aluno

```html
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Aluno extends Authenticatable{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
    'login','password','nivel_acesso','nome','sobrenome','nome_completo','certidao_nascimento',
    'data_nascimento','data_matricula','naturalidade','ra','rm','raca','cor','rg','cpf',
    'email','sexo',

    'telefone','telefone2',
    
    'cidade','endereco','bairro','numero', 'cep',

    'estado_id','escola_id',    
    ];

    protected $hidden = ['password','remember_token'];

    public function responsaveis()
    {        
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Responsavel');
    }

    public function escola()
    {        
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Escola');
    }

    public function estado()
    {        
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Estado');
    }

    public function necessidades()
    {        
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Necessidade');
    }

    public function funcionarios()
    {        
        return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Models\Funcionario','turmas','aluno_id','funcionario_id')
        ->withPivot('serie','nome','professor','periodo','nivel');
    }
}
```

migration associação

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTurmaTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('turmas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('aluno_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('funcionario_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            
            $table->string('nome');
            $table->string('nivel');
            $table->string('serie');
            $table->string('professor'); 
            $table->string('periodo'); 
                                   
            $table->integer('escola_id')->unsigned();
            #$table->primary(['aluno_id','funcionario_id']);            

            $table->foreign('aluno_id')
                ->references('id')->on('alunos')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');                
            
            $table->foreign('funcionario_id')
                ->references('id')->on('funcionarios')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('escola_id')
                ->references('id')->on('escolas')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';            
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('turma');
    }
}
```

controller

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Funcionario;
use App\Models\Aluno;
use Auth;
use DB;


class TurmaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * construtor com auth
     */
    public function __construct(){
      $this->middleware('auth:funcionario');  
    }



    public function getlistar(){     
        #$professores = Funcionario::all()->first();
        $professores = Funcionario::with('alunos')->get();

        return view('turma.index',compact('professores'));
    }

    public function getAdicionar(){
        $professores = Funcionario::where('cargo', '=', 'Professor', 'AND','escola_id','=',Auth::user()->escola_id)->get();
        $alunos = Aluno::where('escola_id','=',Auth::user()->escola_id)->get();
        
        return view('turma.adicionar', compact('professores','alunos'));        
    } 

    public function postCreate(Request $req){        
        $func = Funcionario::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $aluno = $req->aluno;

        $func->turma()->attach($aluno,[
            'nome'=>$req->nome,
            'nivel'=>$req->nivel,
            'serie'=>$req->serie,
            'professor'=>$req->professor,
            'periodo'=>$req->periodo,
            'escola_id'=>$req->escola_id,
        ]);
    }
    
}
```

view

```html
<!-- EXTENDS LAYOUT -->
@extends('layout.app')
<!-- TITULO -->
@section('titulo','Home')


<!-- CONTEUDO -->
@section('conteudo')

 <div class="container">

@if(session()->has('message'))
      <div class="alert alert-success">
          {{ session()->get('message') }}
      </div>
  @endif
 
<h3 align="center">Lista de turmas</h3> 
<br>
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>       
        <th scope="col">nome</th>
        <th scope="col">nivel</th>
        <th scope="col">serie</th>        
        <th scope="col">professor</th>
        <th scope="col">periodo</th>
        <th scope="col">Ação</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($professores as $value)
        <tr scope="row">
          {{-- para 1 so
            @foreach($professores->alunos as $aluno)  
            <td>{{ $value->pivot->nome }}</td>
            @endforeach--}}
          
          <td>{{ $value->alunos()->alunos->nome }}</td>
          {{-- <td>{{ $value->pivot->nivel }}</td>         
          <td>{{ $aluno->pivot->serie }}ª</td>  
          <td>{{ $aluno->pivot->professor }}</td>
          <td>{{ $aluno->pivot->periodo }}</td> --}}
          
          <td class="row">            
            <a class="" href="{{ route('turma.atualizar',$value->id) }}">Editar</a> 
            <a class="" href="{{ route('turma.mostrar',$value->id) }}">Mostrar</a>           
            <a class="" href="{{ route('turma.deletar',$value->id) }}">Deletar</a>            
          </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>

<a id="" class="btn btn-raised btn-secondary" href="{{ route('turma.adicionar') }}">ADICIONAR</a>
  


</div>

@endsection
```

erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

se eu uso o first() que pega so 1 funciona (deixei comentado o first) e to usando o get por que quero mostrar todas as turmas da tabela pivot.

Comment: `$value->alunos()->alunos->nome` parece que você está chamando o nome de um array? Ali não deveria ser um First ou iterar nele?

Comment: first() funciona, mas preciso mostrar as turmas todas em uma lista. como faria isso? poderia dar um exemplo por favor

Comment: Você precisa iterar OU usar algum método que faça algo no estilo implode. Veja a dica 7 desse link http://laraveldaily.com/10-less-known-but-awesome-laravel-collections-methods/

Comment: use um foreach para iterar e mostrar os resultados.

Comment: concordo use um foreach

Comment: Problema resolvido com foreach. obg